# OpenFeint with GameCenter really that easy?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, openfeint

I was reading this: http://www.openfeint.com/ofdeveloper/index.php/kb/article/000089, and it seemed to make out that the implementation of GameCenter with OpenFeint was as simple as adding one plist to the project (after setting up achievements / leaderboards). But is this really the case? I've just implemented this in my project now and can't see any signs of it working. Nor can I see the app in the GameCenter app.

Could it be because I'm writing a universal iPhone / iPad app? Even though the iPhone app is on iOS 4.1?

Can anyone help me out here??

Thanks

James

Comment: What exactly have you done? From the URL you posted: 
"Perform the ususal steps for OpenFeint integration."

Just to make sure: you have implemented OpenFeint as laid out in the docs first?

Comment: Yea, I've followed the docs as usual, weak linked the correct libraries, but to implement game center do I really just include a plist like it says? This seems too little and the implementation doesn't work! The only thing I can think of is that I'm building a universal binary and the iPad isn't on 4.0 yet, but you'd have thought it would work on the iPhone still!

Comment: Have you gone to developer.apple.com and enabled your app for Game Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that because the iPad was below 4.0 when I was doing this, GameCenter wouldn't work, even on the iPhone version.

Upgrade to Xcode 3.2.5 (iOS 4.2) and it will work!

Answer (score 2):

Aside of just including a .plist you must also add

```
"[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], OpenFeintSettingGameCenterEnabled,"
```

to your OpenFeint settings dictionary. It is in the link you mentioned but it's easy to miss and the reason i think you did miss it is you said that you only added "a .plist".

You can verify that GC works when you get the characteristic GC-"Welcome Username" notification when launching your game.

Comment: Yea I have the added! It's in the open feint kb article.